# Exception rasied when signing message with RSA key

Tags: python, cryptography

I've been getting the following error message on macOS and Ubuntu when trying to sign a message with a `rsa` key and `BLAKE2b` hash.

```
InternalError: Unknown OpenSSL error. This error is commonly encountered
when another library is not cleaning up the OpenSSL error stack. If you
are using cryptography with another library that uses OpenSSL try
disabling it before reporting a bug. Otherwise please file an issue at
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues with information on how to
reproduce this. ([])
```

I'm kinda lost as to where to start debugging this. Is there something I'm missing here? Can you not use `BLAKE2b` hashing with `rsa` signing?

```
In [1]: from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, rsa

In [2]: private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
            public_exponent=65537,
            key_size=4096,
            backend=default_backend()
        )

In [3]: message = b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
        signature = private_key.sign(
            message,
            padding.PSS(
                mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.BLAKE2b(64)),
                salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
            ),
            hashes.BLAKE2b(64)
        )
```

Traceback

```
<ipython-input-3-6b4492bdbf5d> in <module>()
      6         salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
      7     ),
----> 8     hashes.BLAKE2b(64)
      9 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in sign(self, data, padding, algorithm)
    413             self._backend, data, algorithm
    414         )
--> 415         return _rsa_sig_sign(self._backend, padding, algorithm, self, data)
    416 
    417 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in _rsa_sig_sign(backend, padding, algorithm, private_key, data)
    220     pkey_ctx = _rsa_sig_setup(
    221         backend, padding, algorithm, private_key, data,
--> 222         backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_sign_init
    223     )
    224     buflen = backend._ffi.new("size_t *")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in _rsa_sig_setup(backend, padding, algorithm, key, data, init_func)
    191     padding_enum = _rsa_sig_determine_padding(backend, key, padding, algorithm)
    192     evp_md = backend._lib.EVP_get_digestbyname(algorithm.name.encode("ascii"))
--> 193     backend.openssl_assert(evp_md != backend._ffi.NULL)
    194     pkey_ctx = backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key._evp_pkey, backend._ffi.NULL)
    195     backend.openssl_assert(pkey_ctx != backend._ffi.NULL)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py in openssl_assert(self, ok)
    104 
    105     def openssl_assert(self, ok):
--> 106         return binding._openssl_assert(self._lib, ok)
    107 
    108     def activate_builtin_random(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py in _openssl_assert(lib, ok)
     73             "issues with information on how to reproduce "
     74             "this. ({0!r})".format(errors_with_text),
---> 75             errors_with_text
     76         )
     77
```

Comment: Having looked through the PSS spec (Sections 8.1 and 9.1.1 in [pkcs#1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017) neither of my earlier hypotheses are correct: PSS padding does not embed the object identifier (OID) for the hash in the signature---so OpenSSL doesn't really need to know about BLAKE2b, nor does PSS restrict the hash to a particular set of algorithms.

Comment: On second glance, I wonder if your salt length isn't too long.  I don't know exactly how to interpret `padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH`, but try using a salt-len that is `< 512 - <hash-len> - 2`

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: I tried `salt_length=256`, but got the same error. Added the Traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty conclusive.  In your trace-back, OpenSSL doesn't know what BLAKE2b is.  Line 192 tries to look it up by name, and line 193 fails the assert because the lookup returned NULL:

```
    192     evp_md = backend._lib.EVP_get_digestbyname(algorithm.name.encode("ascii"))
--> 193     backend.openssl_assert(evp_md != backend._ffi.NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your python version is 3.7, try to `pip install cryptography==2.7`

Comment: pip install cryptography==2.7